# SQL backup size changing

Tags: backup, sql-server-express

I do 4 daily backups of the SQL Server (Express) installed in the company, using the following script

```
sqlcmd -S SERVER_NAME\INSTANCE_NAME -U USER_NSAME -P PASSWORD -o D:\Backups\SQL\log3.txt -Q "BACKUP DATABASE DB_NAME TO BACKUP_DEVICE_NAME
```

Then I upload them to a NAS using Cobian Backup, but I have noticed that the first day Cobian reported 50 GB for the backup and the following days the size went down or up in size with several GB in difference (47 GB, 40, 35 GB, 42 GB, 51 GB, 44 GB, etc).

Why is this happening?, obviously there is some CRUD involved in the daily use of the database, but nothing so drastic to cause such change in the size of the backup. It's a full backup, not a differencial or incremental one.

My boss is asking me why the change in the size of the backup and I don't know what to tell him. I have google it but I can't find an answer...

Comment: You might be better asking this over on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: One thought can be written in texts of different lengths. Backup is not better. Enable compression - the difference will become less. And maybe your boss will not see the difference...

Comment: @spikey_ritchie Will do